# Phone Validation Regular Expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

How would I write a regular expression to format the phone number to 
(XXX) XXX-XXXX and (XXX)XXX-XXXX? I was thinking of writing

([0-9])-+[0-9]-+[0-9]

Its for a model in ASP.NET

Comment: `\((?<AreaCode>\d{3})\)\s*(?<number>\d{3}(?:-|\s*)\d{4})`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming counted quantifiers work in ASP.NET:

```
\([0-9]{3}\)[ ]?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}
```

Comment: I suggest to replace `[ ]?` to `\s*` :)

Comment: @vp_arth if `\d` doesn't exist, maybe `\s` doesn't either? I don't know what flavor ASP.NET uses, so I tried to limit what the regex engine was doing for him! :)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry... Some headbreaking MS standard here :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx#regexnet_topic4

Comment: `ab{2,3}c` matches `abbc, abbbc, aabbcc, aabbbcc`

Comment: `\d` and `\s` both exist here